# How can I know if there is no data to read in Netty ByteBuf?

Tags: java, netty

I'm new to Netty. There is a problem about file transfer confusing me for days. I want to send **image** file from client to server.

The code below is executable. But only I **shutdown** server forcibly can I open received image file normally. Otherwise, it shows "*It looks like you don't have permission to view this file. Check the permissions and try again*". So I want to close fileoutputstream when there is no data in ByteBuf using **ByteBuf.isReadable()**, but the else block in method channelRead in ServerHandler never reach. It's useless.

Besides, if sending **text** file, it can be open normally when server is **alive**. **I don't want to shutdown server  every time after transfer**. Please give me some suggestions to solve it.

This is FileClientHandler

```
public class FileClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private int readLength = 8;

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    sendFile(ctx.channel());
}

private void sendFile(Channel channel) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\1.png");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    for (;;) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[readLength];
        int readNum = bis.read(bytes, 0, readLength);
        // System.out.println(readNum);
        if (readNum == -1) {
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
            return;
        }
        sendToServer(bytes, channel, readNum);
    }
}

private void sendToServer(byte[] bytes, Channel channel, int length)
        throws IOException {
    channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(bytes, 0, length));
}

}
```

This is FileServerHandler

```
public class FileServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private File file = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\2.png");
private FileOutputStream fos;

public FileServerHandler() {
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        } else {
            file.delete();
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        if (buf.isReadable()) {
            buf.readBytes(fos, buf.readableBytes());
            fos.flush();
        } else {
            System.out.println("I want to close fileoutputstream!");
            buf.release();
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Seems like some process locks the file: If you work in unix based system then try to check file permissions. Or try to close channel (on server and client as well) after file transmission is done. But first of all, just **try to close channel after transmission**

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm working on Windows. The key point to me is how can I know file transmission is done in ServerHandler. I tried to close channel after sending in ClientHandler like this: **fis.getChannel().close();**. But it's in vain. And do you know why text file can be open but image can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Fixing the server side

In the Netty world, there are multiple "events":

- [`channelActive`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandler.html#channelActive-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-)
- *[`channelRead`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandler.html#channelRead-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-java.lang.Object-)*
- [`channelReadComplete`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandler.html#channelReadComplete-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-)
- *[`channelInactive`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandler.html#channelInactive-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-)*
- [`exceptionCaught`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandler.html#exceptionCaught-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-java.lang.Throwable-)
- [more...](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandler.html#method.summary)

Of these "events", you probably already knows what `channelRead` does (since your using it), but another one that you seem to need is the `channelInactive`. This one is called when the other endpoint shuts the connection down, and you can use it like this:

```
@Override
public void channelInactive(ctx) {
    System.out.println("I want to close fileoutputstream!");
    fos.close();
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
        // if (buf.isReadable()) { // a buf should always be readable here
            buf.readBytes(fos, buf.readableBytes());
        //    fos.flush(); // flushing is always done when closing
        //} else {
        //    System.out.println("I want to close fileoutputstream!");
        //    buf.release(); // Should be placed in the finally block
        //    fos.flush();
        //    fos.close();
        //}
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
         buf.release(); // Should always be done, even if writing to the file fails
    }
}
```

However, how does the server know the connection has shutdown? At the moment the client does not shut the server down, and instead keep running in the background forever keeping the connection alive.

## Fixing the client side

To properly shutdown the connection from the client, we need to call `channel.close()`, however, we cannot directly insert this before the return line, as this causes a race condition between sending the data, and closing the connection in the network layer, potentially dropping data.

To properly handle these conditions, Netty uses a [`Future`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/Future.html) system that allows code to handle events after asynchronous actions happen.

Lucky for us, Netty already [has a build in solution](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFutureListener.html#CLOSE) for this, we only need to wire it up. To wire this solution up to our code, we have to keep track of the latest [`ChannelFuture`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html) emitted by Netty's write method.

To properly implement this solution, we change `sendToServer` to return the result of the write method:

```
private ChannelFuture sendToServer(byte[] bytes, Channel channel, int length)
        throws IOException {
    return channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(bytes, 0, length));
}
```

Then we keep keep track of this return value, and add a listener containing Netty's build in solution when we want to close the connection:

```
ChannelFuture lastFuture = null;
for (;;) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[readLength];
    int readNum = bis.read(bytes, 0, readLength);
    // System.out.println(readNum);
    if (readNum == -1) {
        bis.close();
        fis.close();
        if(lastFuture == null) { // When our file is 0 bytes long, this is true
            channel.close();
        } else {
            lastFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
        return;
    }
    lastFuture = sendToServer(bytes, channel, readNum);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution is perfect. It not only helps me fix the bug but also acquire a better understanding about Netty. But do you know why text file can be open without closing channel but image can't? Thanks again for your enthusiasm.

Comment: Most text editors allows you to open files that are still in the progress of being written by design, think of files like log files. This is differend for image viewers, were usually a file open for writing means the image is still downloading/something else, and cannot be viewed properly. Since we now close the `Outputstream` towards the file, the image viewer no longer sees the file as being opened for writing

Comment: I see...You are right! I have the last question. That is I found **if(lastFuture == null) {channel.close();}** never execute even if the file is 0 KB. When the future returned is null? Please tell me if you know, I'll appreciate it.