# Can I only close fileoutputstream but the channel is living after I send file by Netty?

Tags: java, netty

Few days ago, I struggled with how to access file sent by NettyClient without killing NettyServer. I got solution on StackOverFlow and the detail of question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871176/how-can-i-know-if-there-is-no-data-to-read-in-netty-bytebuf). The solution is that the client close channel after sending the file, and the server close the fileoutputstream in channelInactive method. The main code is below.

**ClientHandler**

```
public class FileClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private int readLength = 128;

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    sendFile(ctx.channel());
}

private void sendFile(Channel channel) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\1.png");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    ChannelFuture lastFuture = null;
    for (;;) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[readLength];
        int readNum = bis.read(bytes, 0, readLength);
        if (readNum == -1) { // The end of the stream has been reached
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
            lastFuture = sendToServer(bytes, channel, 0);
            if(lastFuture == null) { // When our file is 0 bytes long, this is true
                channel.close();
            } else {
                lastFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
            }
            return;
        }
        lastFuture = sendToServer(bytes, channel, readNum);
    }
}

private ChannelFuture sendToServer(byte[] bytes, Channel channel, int length)
        throws IOException {
    return channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(bytes, 0, length));
}
```

}

**ServerHandler**

```
public class FileServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private File file = new File("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\2.png");
private FileOutputStream fos;

public FileServerHandler() {
    try {
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        } else {
            file.delete();
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("I want to close fileoutputstream!");
    try {
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
        throws Exception {
    ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
    try {
        buf.readBytes(fos, buf.readableBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        buf.release(); // Should always be done, even if writing to the file fails
    }
}
```

}

If now I need to send 10 thousands pictures but every picture is small like 1KB. I have to close and then establish channel frequently. It is a thing wasting many resources. How can I only close fileoutputstream but the channel is alive?

Comment: HTML5 introduced something alike, not closed sessions. However I did not find much at the [java side, just JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/html-five.htm). ***But*** you still can improve the existing code. A larger  buffer size, flushing only at "close", threads (thread pool executor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an idea, and I have not tested it, but rather than sending each file in its own connection, you could start a stream where you send:

1. The number of files to be sent (once)
2. The file info and content (for each file)

   1. The file size
   2. The file name size
   3. The file name
   4. The file content (bytes)

The client would look something like this:

```
public void sendFiles(Channel channel, File...files) {
    ByteBufAllocator allocator = PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT;
    int fileCount = files.length;
    // Send the file count
    channel.write(allocator.buffer(4).writeInt(fileCount));
    // For each file
    Arrays.stream(files).forEach(f -> {         
        try {
            // Get the file content
            byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());
            byte[] fileName = f.getAbsolutePath().getBytes(UTF8);
            // Write the content size, filename and the content
            channel.write(allocator.buffer(4 + content.length + fileName.length)
                    .writeInt(content.length)
                    .writeInt(fileName.length)
                    .writeBytes(fileName)
                    .writeBytes(content)
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // perhaps do something better here.
        }           
    });
    // Flush the channel
    channel.flush();
}
```

On the server side, you would need a slightly more sophisticated channel handler. I was thinking of a replaying decoder. ([Example here](https://gist.github.com/nickman/bc08be142de0b15c5bcdca9adfbf596d))

In that example, the decoder will read all the files and then forward to the next handler which would receive a list of *Upload* instances, but you could send each upload up the pipeline after each received file so you don't allocate as much memory. But the intent is to send all your files in one stream rather than having to connect/disconnect for each file.